# Regex matching but no highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, tmlanguage

I am currently creating a language extension. When adding comments (starts with `$$`), I ran into a hurdle.

```
"comments":{
    "patterns": [{
        "name": "comment.line.sahutorepol",
        "match": "\\$\\$.*$\\n?"
    }]
},
```

Despite the regex matching and being escaped properly, there is no highlighting and the inspect tool confirms that its not properly detected.

[image]

I have tried placing the `match` key outside the `patterns` array, to no change.

Comment: The newline may not need to be double-escaped.  And do you want to include it anyway?

Comment: Yes the newline is most likely not needed, but I added it (and the second backslash) just to be safe.

Comment: The second backslash may be incorrect and cause the regex to look for a literal `\` followed by a `n` which obviously is not what you want.  Did you try it with just `\n` or no newline at all?

Comment: for some reason taking it out of the main include did the trick.

Comment: it was because of a difrenet tag being too greedy